# Sending data from server to client ruby drb

Tags: ruby, drb

I'm trying to make a simple chatroom for 2 users in the same local network. The idea is one of them can be a host and other one a client
here is a little example

server.rb:

```
class ChatSerwer
  def chat( msg)
    puts msg;
  end

  def ChatSerwer.Run
    $SAFE=1;
    @@server = LogSerwer.new
    DRb.start_service('druby://localhost:9000', @@server)
    DRb.thread.join
  end

end

ChatSerwer.Run
```

client.rb:

```
$ip='192.168.1.110'
obj = DRbObject.new_with_uri($ip) 
msg=''
while msg!='exit'
  if obj.respond_to?('chat')
    print "Messege:";msg=gets.chop
    obj.chat(msg);
  end
end
```

But is there a way to send meesege to a client as server ?